# Eigen: Split Array for OpenMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, eigen

I want to split an Eigen dynamic-size array by columns evenly over OpenMP threads.

```
                         thread 0 | thread 1 | thread 2
[[0, 1, 2],                [[0],  |   [[1],  |   [[2],  
 [3, 4, 5],    becomes:     [3],  |    [4],  |    [5],
 [6, 7, 8]]                 [6]]  |    [7]]  |    [8]]
```

I can use the `block` method to do that, but I am not sure if Eigen would recognize the subarray for each thread occupies contiguous memory.

When I read the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Block.html) of block type, has an `InnerPanel` template parameter with the following description:

> `InnerPanel` is true, if the block maps to a set of rows of a row major
>   matrix or to set of columns of a column major matrix (optional). The
>   parameter allows to determine at compile time whether aligned access
>   is possible on the block expression.

Does Eigen know that vectorization over the subarray for each OpenMP thread is possible because each subarray actually occupies contiguous memory?

If not, how to make Eigen know this?

Program:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    // The dimensions of the matrix is not necessary 8 x 8.
    // The dimension is only known at run time.
    Eigen::MatrixXi x(8,8);
    x.fill(0);
    int n_parts = 3;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n_parts; ++i) {
        int st = i * x.cols() / n_parts;
        int en = (i + 1) * x.cols() / n_parts;
        x.block(0, st, x.rows(), en - st).fill(i);
    }
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Result (`g++ test.cpp -I<path to eigen includes> -fopenmp -lgomp`):

```
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: SO must be sleeping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that a block expression is indeed occupying contiguous memory, use `middleCols` (or `leftCols` or `rightCols`) instead:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
template<typename XprType, int BlockRows, int BlockCols, bool InnerPanel>
void inspectBlock(const Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>& block)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

int main() {
    Eigen::MatrixXi x(8,8);
    inspectBlock(x.block(0, 1, x.rows(), 2));
    inspectBlock(x.middleCols(1, 2));
}
```

Result:

> ```
> void inspectBlock(const Eigen::Block<ArgType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>&) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1>; int BlockRows = -1; int BlockCols = -1; bool InnerPanel = false]
> void inspectBlock(const Eigen::Block<ArgType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>&) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<int, -1, -1>; int BlockRows = -1; int BlockCols = -1; bool InnerPanel = true]
> ```

Note: `-1` is the value of `Eigen::Dynamic`, i.e., not fixed at compile time.

And of course, if your matrix was row major, you could split int `topRows`, `middleRows` or `bottomRows`, instead.

Comment: Does that also let Eigen know the memory alignment of the subarrays?

Comment: Hmm. InnerPanel is true. Let me test what will happen if the array's dimension/boundary of the sub-arrays are not a multiple of the size of simd registers.

Comment: I'm not aware that Eigen can be told that sub-blocks are in fact aligned. (I would have thought `Ref` can be told only to accept aligned blocks, but I did not manage to produce a working example) -- If you really desperately need that, you can make a manual construction using an `AlignedMap`.